# Unique Value for Two Strings

Tags: c#

This seems like a fairly simple problem, but the solution is eluding me:

If I have the following two strings:

```
string str1 = "Ping";
string str2 = "Pong";
```

I'm needing an algorithm to create a unique value for the two strings, no matter what order they are in. For example:

UniqueValue(str1, str2) and UniqueValue(str2, str1) should return the exact same value.

EDIT: UniqueValue returns a string. I understand it won't be "truly" unique, but a hash-like value will work.

Thanks,
Tyler

Comment: Could you be more specific about the return type of UniqueValue?

Comment: What would the output of UniqueValue be for these strings?

Comment: How unique is unique? Could never be replicated by any other combination? Ping and Pong result in the same unique value until the end of time? What's the resulting type? You have left a lot out.

Comment: See Justin's answer.  It can be truly, truly unique, and you don't have to settle for a hash if you have O(N) storage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort the strings.

Convert `/` to `//` and `;` to `/;` in each of the strings.

Concatenate the strings, putting a `;` between each.

Comment: This guarantees that the created value is unique, and that the combinations "ab" "cdef" and "abc" "def" produce different results, even if they contan the separator character (i.e., `;`). The downside is that it will be as long as the strings themselves, but that's necessary if you want the hash to be one-to-one.

Comment: Excellent!  Beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 3):

You can Xor the hashcodes.

```
static string UniqueValue (string str1, string str2)
{
   return (str1.GetHashCode () ^ str2.GetHashCode()).ToString ();
}
```

Edit: Or, you can generate this string:

```
if (str2 > str1)
   return str1+str2;
return str2+str1;
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could concatenate the strings and sort them.

Comment: I think xoring is better. Sorting would introduce unneeded overhead.

Comment: Your edit produces the same result for "ab" + "cdef" and "abc" + "def". You need a unique separator, and to escape that separator where it may exist in the composing strings.

Comment: As I understood the question, the result had to be the same for given input, not unique accross the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some sort of hash, but I don't see any algorithm that would produce a 100% guaranteed unique string that could never be duplicated by any other two strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would hash them with SHA1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx

To determine in which orientation they should be in when concatenated, use `String.CompareTo`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compareto.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int UniqueValue(params string[] strings)
{
    return String.Join("~", strings.AsEnumerable<string>()
                                   .OrderBy<string, string>(s => s)
                                   .ToArray<string>())
                 .GetHashCode();
}
```

This, of course, is provided that you don't need *complete* uniqueness and that a hash code is good enough.